# can local storage store the whole page

Tags: javascript, html

so I have seen a lot of people using local storage to store certain parts of a web page but not an entire web page is it possible? , if so how? , if not is there a way to store an entire web pages data so the user can come back to it how they left it?

Comment: @Jocket I tried what the comment said it returned undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done if you use javascript to save document.body.innerHTML into the webstorage and you use javascript to load it back from the storage when the page is loaded next time. If the web page is not in the webstorage, you could redirect the user to the web page.

But this depends on the design of your web page and if there is session index etc in the body of the web page.

You should also think of some way to handle versions. You dont want your users only use the cached version of your web page, but it should be updated once you update your web page.

The session storage is ~5mbit, so you cant save very much, especially not pictures.

Comment: This is going to lose all event handlers and any active scripts and any JS state. It is very unlikely to work the way you hope, and very unlikely to be the solution to whatever the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Since LocalStorage allows you to store about 5MB~ you can store a full webpage there and then just call it into a `document.write()`.

The following code does it:

Storing it:

```
var HTML = ""; //html of the page goes here
localStorage.setItem("content", HTML);
```

Retrieving it:

```
document.write(localStorage['content']);
```

Although this is possible it is common practice you only save settings and load them up into the right elements rather than the entire web page.

Comment: @torazaburo you can access it by two ways I update the answer please look.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really answering your question, but, if you are only curious how this can be done and don't need to have wide browser support, I suggest you look into Service Workers, as making websites offline is something that they solve very well.

One of their many capabilities is that they can act as a proxy for any request your website makes, and respond with locally saved data, instead of going to the server.

This allows you to write your application code exactly the same way as you would normally, with the exception of initializing the ServiceWorker (this is done only once)

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers
https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/

Answer (score -1):

Local storage it's actually just an endpoint: has an IP address and can be accessed from the web.
First of all, you need to make sure that you're DNS service points on your Index page.
For example, if your Local-storage's ip is 10.10.10.10 and the files on that local-storage is organized like:

- contants:

  - pages:

    - index.html
    - page2.html
  - images:

    - welcome.png

So you can point your DNS like:
10.10.10.10/index  ->  /contants/pages/index.html

In most of the web frameworks (web framework it's a library that provide built in tools that enable you to build your web site with more functionality and more easily) their is a built in module called 'route' that provide more functionality like this.

In that way, from you index.html file you can import the entire web site, for example:

and in your routes you define for example:
For all the files with the .html extension, route to -> 10.10.10.10/contants/pages/
For all the files with the .png/.jpg extension, route to -> 10.10.10.10/contants/images/

Comment: No, local storage is **not** an endpoint and does **not** have an IP address and **cannot** be accessed from the web. You're confusing local storage with something else.

Comment: Did you confuse localstorage with localhost?

Answer (score -1):

Local storage is usually for storing key and value pairs, storing a whole page will be a ridiculous idea. Try instead a Ajax call which Returns an partial view. Use that for the purpose of manipulation in DOM

Comment: No, local storage is for storing arbitrary strings.